# How is this chained indexing?

Tags: python, pandas

I get `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame` warning when trying to run the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3),
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = df[(df.A > 0) | (df.B > 0)]
df2.at[-1, 'C'] = df['C'].iloc[-1]
```

How is this chained indexing?

***UPDATE***

I think I misused the `-1` index - seems in this case it doesn't return the last row like I expected. Replaced it with `df2.at[df2.index[-1], 'C'] = df['C'].iloc[-1]` and the warning went away.

Comment: Unable to repro. What version of pandas and how is `df` created?

Comment: The tricky thing with `SettingWithCopyWarning` is that its cause can be a much ealier line of code. I'm fairly sure that if you copy this in a clean shell/script/notebook, you won't have any issue.

Comment: Did you read [the docs](//pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)? This example seems really similar to this situation, but I'm not an expert: `foo = df[['bar', 'baz']]  # Is foo a view? A copy? Nobody knows!` ... `foo['quux'] = value  # We don't know whether this will modify df or not!`

Comment: If it helps, we also have a canonical question: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](/q/20625582/4518341)

Comment: I'm able to repro intermittently on Pandas 2.0.3. Based on the docs, intermittently is as expected: *"Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees)"*

Comment: @wjandrea I am not trying to modify df. I am trying to modify df2. Are you saying that df can possibly get modified in this case? I think now I am starting to understand the point of ```copy()``` function.

Comment: @Viktor yes, because this line reports the warning, but its cause is due to a previous line. Have you tested your 3 lines in a clean environment as I suggested? Can you still reproduce the warning?

Comment: @Viktor I think because you're assigning to a new index (-1), it's not possible for `df` to be modified, but the layer of code that produces the warning doesn't check that. But again, I'm not an expert. I suppose best practice is to always explicitly `.copy()`.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76312603/19123103) helps. Basically, your boolean indexing filters out more than one row but your `at` expression is only adding one new row.